# How to format two dates with different format?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, momentjs

I use `md-datepicker` and I want to format `start_date` with word "from"
and `end_date` with word "to".
I tried to use:

```
$mdDateLocale.formatDate = function (date) {
    if (date) {
        var formatedDate = moment(date).format('[to] DD-MM-YYYY');
        return formatedDate;
    } else {
        return ' ';
    }
};
```

and

```
$mdDateLocale.formatDate = function (date) {
    if (date) {
        var formatedDate = moment(date).format('[from] DD-MM-YYYY');
        return formatedDate;
    } else {
        return ' ';
    }
};
```

But it set "from" to all dates.

Comment: How you identify `start_date` and `end_date`? I fear that you gave too little information to let us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using two different date pickers. You could use a keyword or something maybe:

```
$mdDateLocale.formatDate = function (date, keyword) {
    if (date) {
        var formatedDate = moment(date).format('[' + keyword + '] DD-MM-YYYY');
        return formatedDate;
    } else {
        return ' ';
    }
};
```

and call it like that:

```
formatDate(date, 'from');
formatDate(date, 'to');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your 'date' is newer then now or older and then set the format.

```
$mdDateLocale.formatDate = function (date) {
  if (date) {
    if (new Date(date) > new Date()) {
       return moment(date).format('[to] DD-MM-YYYY');
    } else {
       return moment(date).format('[from] DD-MM-YYYY');
    }
    return formatedDate;
  } else {
    return ' ';
  }
};
```

Comment: startDate and endDate can be both older than now

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it like this:

```
 $mdDateLocale.formatDate = function (date) {
                if (date) {
                    if(date == vm.startDate) {
                        var formatedDate = moment(date).format('[From:] DD-MM-YYYY');
                        return formatedDate;
                    } else if(date == vm.endDate) {
                        var formatedDate = moment(date).format('[To:] DD-MM-YYYY');
                        return formatedDate;
                    } else {
                        var formatedDate = moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
                        return formatedDate;
                    }

                } else {
                    return ' ';
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code:

```
var startDate = moment(some_start_date_value);
var endDate = moment(some_end_date_value);
var differenceDays = startDate.diff(endDate, 'days');
//you also can use 'minutes', 'hours', etc...
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/